# Radio button returning false from another class

Tags: c#, multithreading, radio-button

Happy New Year Everyone!

I'm having a problem sending a boolean value from a Form to a class in which works through the code for the Form to change.

So I have a radioButton (rb2) which when clicked starts a thread. However, what I need is the radioButton to return true or false to the other class.

```
public class Airport : Form
{
    public RadioButon rb2;

    public void rb2_Checked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (rb2.Checked == true)
       {
           thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(p2.Start2));
           thread3.Start();
       }
    }
}
```

Below is the class which needs to get the value true of false from the Airport class. But when I print it out (r) it always prints out false. I have tried a couple of things and they have not worked as of yet.

```
class Hubs
{
    public void Start2
    {
        Airport ap = new Airport();
        RadioButton r = ap.rb2;
        Console.WriteLine(r);

        if(r.Checked == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check r");
        }

    }
}
```

Anyone got any ideas that could be causing the new radioButton to print false constantly in my new class?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the Airport form and a new instance of the radiobutton. This new instance has no knowledge of the checked state of the original radiobutton rb2 on the initial instance of the Airport form.

Comment: Cheers, for the answer, but how else am I meant to do it?

Comment: Pass the instance of Airport from the form to the method

Comment: But thinking again about it. If you start the thread when the radiobutton is checked you already know that is checked. So why do you need to get this info from the original form?

Comment: @Steve something I didn't add was that I have multiple radio buttons and the layout is complex, but I need it to ignore some code if it returns true and opposite if false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding a parameter to your method that takes in an instance of an Airport class:

```
class Hubs
{
    public void Start2(object airport)
    {
        var ap = airport as Airport;
        if (ap == null) return;

        RadioButton r = ap.rb2;
        Console.WriteLine(r);

        if (r != null && r.Checked)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check r");
        }
    }
}
```

Then pass the instance of Airport (using `this`) to the method when you call it:

```
public class Airport : Form
{
    public RadioButon rb2;

    public void rb2_Checked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rb2 != null && rb2.Checked)
        {
            var x = new Hubs();
            var thread3 = new Thread(x.Start2);
            thread3.Start(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure you can read that UI control from another thread. Passing just the state true/false?